# A data persistence library for AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, breeze, data-persistence

There is an [alpha](https://github.com/emberjs/data) for Ember Js and also [Persistence](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs). Is there something similar for AngularJs (or it is in plan)? 
Maybe there is something that is framework independent?

What I need is actual library which enables these:

1. To define my object model
2. To define relations between models (hasMeny, foreignKey)
3. To enable REST calls and caching of models on client

**UPDATE**

I found these (credits go to [Miroslav](http://blog.miroslavpopovic.com/))

- http://www.breezejs.com/
- http://amplifyjs.com/
- http://reclinejs.com/

Answer (score 14):

At the and I finished with [BREEZEJS](http://www.breezejs.com/)
It offered best documentation and sample and it is very straightforward.

**UPDATE**: Recently new library created called [ngActiveResource](https://github.com/FacultyCreative/ngActiveResource). It is simple and straightforward.

Comment: Found any libraries that allow you to create an adapter for custom data? Or maybe a way to do so using ngActiveResource?

Comment: ngActiveResource uses a lot of conventions (unless you decide to use parts of it and customize) and is great for RESTFull and has other limitations (you cannot use envelope in your code etc). It really requires real REST.

Comment: Found another possible candidate called [Angular Data](http://angular-data.codetrain.io/)